# MSXML2.XMLHTTP generating different results than if I simply visited page in a web browser

Tags: http, vba, excel, msxml

I use Excel VBA to download the page source of certain websites the following way:

```
    Public Function GetPage(URL As String) As String
        Dim oX As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
        oX.Open "Get", URL, False
        oX.Send
        GetPage = oX.responseText
    End Function
```

However, after careful inspection I notice that the HTML source that this code returns is different than the HTML source that's returned when I visit the site with a web browser.

[This is the website I'm visiting](http://rrcsearch.neubus.com/esd-rrc/index.php?subaction=1&profile=0&show_district=on&district=&show_field_no=on&field_no=&show_field_name=on&field_name=&show_lease_id=on&lease_id=&show_lease_name=on&lease_name=&show_fluid_no=on&fluid_no=&show_api_no=on&api_no=36537174&show_docket_no=on&docket_no=&docket_type=&city=&app_name=&app_file_date_from=&app_file_date_to=&final_order_date_from=&final_order_date_to=&admin_close_date_from=&admin_close_date_to=&t4permit_no=&county=&operator_name=&operator_no=&company_id=&company_name=&year=&drilling_no=&commingling_permit_no=&county_name=&county_number=&survey_name=&survey_section_number=&alternate_survey_name=&abstract_number=&scan_date_from=&scan_date_to=&ipp=10#results). At the bottom of the page, it lists two results. Now, if I visit that URL using my GetPage function, it returns the main page's HTML but it doesn't include any of the results--the source specifically says "0 result(s) found." What gives? It doesn't appear to be using JavaScript to replace certain HTML elements, so I'm at a loss. I do notice that when I visit the site myself it goes slowly, but when I run the VBA HTTP request it seems almost instantaneous. Perhaps I have to wait for something?

Does anyone know why I can't find these results if I do an HTTP request through VBA?

Comment: When I use your code I get an error page returned complaining about ** column "results" does not exist**  No idea why that errors and the exact same URL works in the browser.

Comment: My answer seems to have crossed over with Tim's comment. It looks like poor URL parsing by the neubus.com site as a fragment is perfectly legal after the query portion of a URI. From RFC 3986: "The generic URI syntax consists of a hierarchical sequence of
components referred to as the scheme, authority, path, query, and
fragment." and one of the examples they give is `foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose`

Comment: It's also possible that the `XMLHTTP` object is encoding the `#` character and causing the URL to become mangled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing the fragment identifier `#results` from the end of the URL. Whilst this is perfectly legal syntax for a URL, it seems to cause an issue here as I see this in the response:

```
 ERROR:  column "results" does not exist
LINE 1: ... = 'O') AND (parent_part_info IS NULL))) LIMIT 10#results OF...
```

When I run the URL without the `#results` part, the response comes back after a couple of seconds with the same 2 results shown when visiting the URL in a browser

Also `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` is a synonym  for `MSXML2.XMLHTTP30` - i.e. the version originally from the "Microsoft XML, v3.0" library. If you are using the "Microsoft XML, v6.0" library then it's usually advisable to change  the reference to `MSXML2.XMLHTTP60`. See [this Microsoft blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2006/10/23/using-the-right-version-of-msxml-in-internet-explorer.aspx)